# filtering multidimentional array in PHP by some values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need to fix existing code to write values only if value 0, 1 and 2 are the same but I can't reach it. For example I wand to see elements in the first case (1=1=1) but not on the second one (2!1=1).

```
$plist=array(
        array('100%&nbsp;CSB','75%&nbsp;CSB','Sans&nbsp;CSB','MSN&nbsp;100%CSB','MSN&nbsp;sans&nbsp;CSB'),
        array(1,1,1,10.4,9.09,),
        array(2,1,1,20.4,17.84,),
        array(2,2,1,21.7,18.97,),
        array(2,2,2,31.4,27.89,),
        array(3,2,2,40.5,36.31,),
        array(3,3,2,42.8,38.44,),
        array(3,3,3,52.2,47.09,),
        array(4,3,3,60.7,54.78,),
        array(4,4,3,64,57.77,),
        array(4,4,4,73.3,66.18,),
        array(5,4,4,81,73.15,),
        array(5,5,4,85.2,77.01,),
        array(5,5,5,94.2,85.45,),
        array(6,5,5,101.2,92.01,),
        array(6,6,5,106.1,96.6,)
    );
    $cnt=0;
    foreach ($plist as $pligne) {

        $cnt++;
        if ($cnt==19) {
            echo '</table></td><td bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;</td><td valign="top">';
            echo '<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="hoverTable"><tr>';
            foreach($plist[0] as $ke) {
                echo '<td align="right">'.$ke.'&nbsp;</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';

        }
        $minu=floatval($pligne[3])-(floatval($pligne[3])-floatval($pligne[4]))*0.25;
        echo '<tr onmouseover="document.form.abc.value='.$pligne[3].'; document.form.scsb.value='.$pligne[4].'; 
                document.form.min.value='.round($minu,2).';     "
                onclick="allid.listeplex.style.display=\'none\'; allid.affplex.style.display=\'block\';""
             >';
        foreach($pligne as $ke) {
            echo '<td align="right">'.$ke.'&nbsp;</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
```

My first idea was something like :

```
if($plist[$cnt][0]===$plist[$cnt][1] AND $plist[$cnt][0]===$plist[$cnt][1] AND $plist[$cnt][0]===$plist[$cnt][1]){
}
```

but it's not working (not sur where to put it or which variable name use)

Comment: That IF is making the same test 3 times? I assume you should be using a different index on the second and third test ???

Comment: FYI, that’s filtering, not sorting.

Comment: Thanks, it was an attention error (testing two times the same thing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that 1st equals 2nd and 1st equals 3rd.

Inside of `foreach ($plist as $pligne) {` use this condition:

```
if ($pligne[0] === $pligne[1] && $pligne[0] === $pligne[2]) {
```

You don't need to manually increment `$cnt` in your snippet, you can declare `$cnt` in your `foreach()` loop and omit the manual incrementation step (`$cnt++;`).

```
foreach ($plist as $cnt => $pligne) {
```

---

If you need to unconditionally allow the first row in your array, then just check if the `$cnt` is zero.

```
if (!$cnt || ($pligne[0] === $pligne[1] && $pligne[0] === $pligne[2])) {
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly, but tell him to put it inside the foreach as well, as he is _not sure where to put it or which variable name to use_

Comment: Careful, OP has to avoid this test on occurance[0] as that occ does not look like the other occurances in his array